# Combine different text's lines as table

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I want to combine two text files:

Firts file：

```
1|Monkey
2|Tiger
3|Crane
4|Mantis
```

Second file:

```
|Brown
|Orange
|White
|Green
```

That in result the would become this:

```
1|Monkey|Brown
2|Tiger |Orange
3|Crane |White
4|Mantis|Green
```

Any ideas how to do this?

**Update:**

Ah, found it! The working example:

```
txt1="""1|Monkey
2|Tiger
3|Crane
4|Mantis"""
txt2="""|Brown
|Orange
|White
|Green"""
txt3=txt2.splitlines(True)
a=0
r=""
for l in txt1.splitlines():
    r = r+  l + txt3[a]
    if a < len(txt1.splitlines(True)):
        a = a+1 
print(r)
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done this way

```
with open('first.txt', 'r') as ffile, open('second.txt', 'r') as sfile, open('result.txt', 'w') as rfile:
    for lines in zip(ffile.read().splitlines(), sfile.read().splitlines(keepends=True)):
        rfile.write(''.join(lines))
```

Comment: hm, I didn't know that there is zip command... Well this one is better.